# Is it okay to say "How much is that part?"

Tags: grammar

So I was asking for the price of a car part, and I immediately spoke "How much is that part?". The person I was talking to understood my question, but since it's not my first language I would like to ask if it's correct.

Thank you

Comment: The question makes perfect sense. Maybe he didn't understand which part?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is perfectly okay to phrase the question that way. You could also say "How much does that/the part cost".